# Python-Maths-Project Euler P23

Tags: python, math

```
def isAbundant(testNum):
    total = 1
    divisor = 2 
    while divisor < (testNum/2  + 1):
        if(testNum%divisor == 0):
            total = total + divisor
        divisor = divisor + 1   
    if total > testNum:
        result = True
    else:
        result = False
    return result

#create a list of abundant numbers
i = 12
listOfAbunNo = []
sums = []
while i < 28112:
    if isAbundant(i) == True:
        listOfAbunNo.append(i)
    i = i+1 
    print(i)
# create list of sums of Abundant numbers
i = 0
print(len(listOfAbunNo))
while i < len(listOfAbunNo):
    j = i                       # i and j are abundant numbers (indexes) to sum
    while j <len(listOfAbunNo):  
        sums.append(listOfAbunNo[i]+listOfAbunNo[j])
        j=j+1
    i = i+1
#remove duplicates 
sums.sort() 
i = 1
while i<len(sums):
    if (sums[i-1] == sums[i]):
        sums.remove(sums[i-1])
    else:
        i = i + 1
#calc total
print(str(sum[12,28111] - sum(sums)))
```

This is my code for the problem https://projecteuler.net/problem=23, is it correct? and how can I optimize it?

Problem 
A perfect number is a number for which the sum of its proper divisors is exactly equal to the number. For example, the sum of the proper divisors of 28 would be 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28, which means that 28 is a perfect number.

A number n is called deficient if the sum of its proper divisors is less than n and it is called abundant if this sum exceeds n.

As 12 is the smallest abundant number, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16, the smallest number that can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers is 24. By mathematical analysis, it can be shown that all integers greater than 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers. However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.

Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.

Comment: @DeepSpace Well the OP has asked - *is it correct?* - not sure if they would allow such questions in codereview.

Comment: *"is it correct"* ...does it give you the right answer?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it is taking too long to run through the code

Comment: @DeepSpace About "is it correct?" type of questions, please read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

> is it correct?

**Yes - except for the last step**, calculating the total with `print(str(sum[12,28111] - sum(sums)))` doesn't work:

1. `sums` contains all composite numbers, also those which are higher than 28112. Try `print(max(sums))` and you'll get `56220`. So you can't just add all those numbers up, many of those shouldn't count to the total.
2. You should provide the sum of "all the positive integers (...)" so you should start from 1, not 12.
3. `sum[12, 28111]` is not valid Python syntax, try `sum(range(12, 28111))`

You could do the last step as follows: Generate a list of all non-composite numbers, the numbers you want to add, and then sum those:

```
non_composites = sum([i for i in range(1, 28112) if i not in sums])
print(str(non_composites))
```

---

> and how can I optimize it?

**Removing duplicates**: You could optimize the 'removing duplicates'-part:

```
#remove duplicates 
sums.sort() 
i = 1
while i<len(sums):
    if (sums[i-1] == sums[i]):
        sums.remove(sums[i-1])
    else:
        i = i + 1
```

Can be written more pythonic (and faster) as

```
#remove duplicates 
sums = list(set(sums))
```

Which will make `sums` a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), removing all its duplicates, then making it a list again.

**isAbundant**-function: Instead of

```
if total > testNum:
    result = True
else:
    result = False
return result
```

you can write

```
return total > testNum
```

**list of sums**: This part can also be simplified from

```
# create list of sums of Abundant numbers
i = 0
print(len(listOfAbunNo))
while i < len(listOfAbunNo):
    j = i
    while j <len(listOfAbunNo):  
        sums.append(listOfAbunNo[i]+listOfAbunNo[j])
        j=j+1
    i = i+1
```

to

```
for i in range(len(listOfAbunNo)):
    for j in range(i, len(listOfAbunNo)):
        sums.append(listOfAbunNo[i]+listOfAbunNo[j])
```

---

So you're whole code now looks like this:

```
import time

def isAbundant(testNum):
    total = 1
    divisor = 2 
    while divisor < (testNum/2  + 1):
        if(testNum%divisor == 0):
            total = total + divisor
        divisor = divisor + 1   
    return total > testNum

start = time.time()
#create a list of abundant numbers
listOfAbunNo = []
for i in range(12, 28124):
    if isAbundant(i):
        listOfAbunNo.append(i)

# create list of sums of abundant numbers
sums = []
for i in range(len(listOfAbunNo)):
    for j in range(i, len(listOfAbunNo)):
        sums.append(listOfAbunNo[i]+listOfAbunNo[j])

#remove duplicates 
sums = list(set(sums))

#calc total
non_composites = sum([i for i in range(1, 28124) if i not in sums])
print(str(non_composites))
print('finished in ' + str(time.time()-start) + 's')
```

I added a timing function and the code returns the correct result in about 40s on my machine.

Comment: But if I have a + b, i dont need b + a, and since j starts at i, I will get 12 + 12 = 24, when i = j =0, Or am I missing something

Comment: @lexist You're correct! I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Iexist Changed my answer, just going through your code.